# Cannot drag and drop after$AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

If I drag in csets.php page, I can drag and drop items. But when I use onchange to change categories item. New item after$AJAX and query cannot drag.

Csets.php

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="options">
  <?php 
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM item_head ORDER BY ihead_id DESC";
    $objQuery = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)){
  ?>
  <img width="150" height="120" src="item_head/<?php echo $row['filesName'];?>" id="drag1<?php echo $row['head_id'];?>" class="drag"</img>
<?php } ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function selectCa(){
 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 var value = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("options").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "checkQuery.php?value="+value, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

CheckQuery.php

```
<?php
$value = $_GET["value"];

//query head items
if($value == "head"){   
  $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM item_head ORDER BY ihead_id DESC";
  $objQuery = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)){ ?>

  <img width="150" height="120" src="item_head/<?php echo $row['filesName'];?>" id="drag1<?php echo $row['head_id'];?>" class="drag"></img>

 <?php } 
  }else if($value == "body"){   
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM item_body ORDER BY ibody_id DESC";
    $objQuery = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)){
 ?>

 <img width='150' height='120' src='item_body/<?php echo $row['filesName'];?>' id='drag1' class='drag'></img>

 <?php      
 }
 }else if($value == "shoes"){   
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM item_shoes ORDER BY ishoes_id DESC";
    $objQuery = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)){
 ?>

 <img width='150' height='120' src='item_shoes/<?php echo $row['filesName'];?>' id='drag1' class='drag'></img>

 <?php } 
 } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the AJAX request has completed, you should re-initiate the draggable function. When content is loaded via AJAX, Javascript doesn't target those elements that loaded AFTER you called the initial draggable function.

Comment: How to re-initiate the draggable function?

Comment: How are you currently making your elements draggable? Presumably running a function at page load to make the selected elements draggable. Just recall that function after the AJAX is complete.

Comment: I use myFunction() that I use to select element drag and drop in selectCa() function but it cannot work it.

Comment: I can do it nowww !! Thank you very much for your recommendation :)